# unwindToList and custom tableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a VC which contains a tableView. The tableView uses my custom tableViewCell from a xib file.

How can i link(click drag storyboard) a button in the custom tableViewCell to an unwindToList action in the VC where the tableView is located?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first type the unwindToList method in your fist view controller. It will then show for you to select when you control-drag your button to the Exit icon in the dock of your custom tableViewCell view controller.

Here go down to the part titled "Create an Unwind Segue to Navigate Back":
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html

Does this help?